# Nested array into backbone model

Tags: javascript, arrays, backbone.js

I have the following backbone model:

```
var Info = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'http://localhost:8080/info',
    defaults : {
        nombre: '',
        tipo : '',
        telf : 0,
        icono : '',
        direccion:[{
            direccion:'',
            latitud:'',
            longitud:''
        }]
    },
    idAttribute:"_id"
});
```

I want to change the value of the "direccion" atribute of the array inside "direccion".

I have used the following code but is not working:

```
//clone the array
var direccionArray = _.clone(this.collection.get(idInfo).get('direccion'));
direccionArray.direccion = this.$('#dir-info-edit').val();
```

Here I obtain the array with the values changed and works fine:

```
console.log(direccionArray);
```

Now I set the array into my backbone model as follow and is not working (the model don't change) and I get the same model (changing other atributes like "nombre" or "tipo" works fine but not with the array):

```
this.collection.get(idInfo).set('direccion',direccionArray);
console.log(this.collection.get(idInfo));
```

Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

As stated `direccion` attribute of model is an array that contains object at index 0.

When you trying to do:

```
//clone the array
var direccionArray = _.clone(this.collection.get(idInfo).get('direccion'));
direccionArray.direccion = this.$('#dir-info-edit').val();
```

This will not update the `direccionArray[0]`, which you want to update, and just will add new attribute to your array object.

What you want to do is:

```
direccionArray[0].direccion = this.$('#dir-info-edit').val();
```

Try `console.dir(direccionArray)` the old array and you will see the difference.

**Update:**

Please see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vvahans/khqd7zfo/13/) jsfiddle with the explanation of the issue. The main reason for your case can be that you are tring to get the value with jquery's `val()` method on an element that is not an input.

Comment: I changed but still my model is not changing. The problem comes right here this.collection.get(idInfo).set('direccion',direccionArray);

Comment: @bruno can you create a fiddle or add script in the answer, it should work?

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you mean :(

Comment: A thank you I have never used fiddle :) nice tool. Ok I see but it is just what I have but I don't know why is not working to me... I have to take a look to the code step by step and find whats going on.

Comment: Sure. But from the initial question I can see only mentioned issues.

Comment: I get the .val() from an input element and if I show the value obtained in the console I get the value selected by the user. The only strange thing that it is not working on my code is the last line that you write in the fiddle infoModel.set('direccion', direccionArray); if I show my model in the console after do that I get exatly the same model before changing the array... So Im getting crazy

Comment: Hi I couldn't create a fiddle because I need to many files and it is not running into fiddle. Could I show you my repo files?https://bitbucket.org/brunoescalona/bttserviciosrest/src/ae81d9b9e02c/static/js/model/?at=materialize here I have my models and collection (Info.js and Infos.js)      https://bitbucket.org/brunoescalona/bttserviciosrest/src/ae81d9b9e02c2861d61f3056ebfbdcda7f8dc45d/static/js/view/ViewEditInfo.js?at=materialize&fileviewer=file-view-default and here my view. Thank you for all your support in advance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118734/discussion-between-vahan-vardanyan-and-bruno).